# Make a relation 3 django models and add filter

Tags: python, mysql, django, model, relation

How do I make a relation 3 django models?

I would like to be able to do the mysql query, but as I do with django, I want to relate 3 models and additionally I want to add a filter by user ID

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT * FROM hospetaje 
inner join usuario on (Usuario_idUsuario=idUsuario)
inner join pago on (idHospetaje=Hospetaje_idHospetaje)
where idUsuario = 5
```

**My model is**

```
class Usuario(models.Model):
  idusuario = models.AutoField(db_column='idUsuario', primary_key=True)  
  cc = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=45)
  nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
  apellido = models.CharField(max_length=20)
  fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField()
  sexo = models.CharField(max_length=6)
  e_mail = models.CharField(db_column='e-mail', max_length=30)
  telefono = models.CharField(max_length=10)
  usuario = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  contrasena = models.CharField(max_length=10)
 tipousuario_idtipousuario = models.ForeignKey(Tipousuario, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='TipoUsuario_idTipoUsuario')

class Pago(models.Model):
  idpago = models.AutoField(db_column='idPago', primary_key=True)  
  fechapago = models.DateTimeField(db_column='fechaPago') 
  fechapagada = models.DateField(db_column='fechaPagada') 
  valor = models.FloatField()
  hospetaje_idhospetaje = models.ForeignKey(Hospetaje, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Hospetaje_idHospetaje')  

class Hospetaje(models.Model):
  idhospetaje = models.AutoField(db_column='idHospetaje', primary_key=True) 
  usuario_idusuario = models.ForeignKey('Usuario', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Usuario_idUsuario')  
  habitacion_idhabitacion = models.ForeignKey(Habitacion, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Habitacion_idHabitacion') 
  fechainicio = models.DateField(db_column='fechaInicio')  
  fechafinal = models.DateField(db_column='fechaFinal', blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Please update the formatting on your models its a bit hard to read at the moment.

Comment: Can you [re-write the question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that it asks *one* thing, in such a way as there is *one* correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You've already created the "relations" between your models by defining [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) fields.

You can access related models this way:

```
pago = Pago.objects.first()
pago.hospetaje_idhospetaje
```

The Django docs have some good [examples on how to access Many-to-One relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).